# Retrieving predictions for hold-out folds in caret

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I am wondering how to recover the cross-validation predictions. I am interested in building a stacking model manually ([like here in point 3.2.1](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/)) and I would need the model's predictions for each of the hold-out folds. I am attaching a short example.

```
# load the library
library(caret)
# load the iris dataset
data(cars)
# define folds
cv_folds <- createFolds(cars$Price, k = 5, list = TRUE)
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", index = cv_folds, savePredictions = 'final')
# fix the parameters of the algorithm
# train the model
model <- caret::train(Price~., data=cars, trControl=train_control, method="gbm", verbose = F)
# looking at predictions
model$pred

# verifying the number of observations
nrow(model$pred[model$pred$Resample == "Fold1",])
nrow(cars)
```

I would like to know what are the predictions that come from estimating the model on folds 1-4 and evaluating on fold 5 etc. Looking at `model$pred` does not seem to give me what I need.

Comment: you might want to look at [this answer on cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret)

Comment: I have seen this answer, however, I have some doubts about it. When I run `subset(model$pred, Resample == "Fold01")` I obtain a data.frame of size equal to 9 folds used for estimation. However, what I would like to obtain is the opposite, predictions for the 10% of data not used for estimation.

Comment: @abu this is incorrect: From your example: `nrow(model$pred[model$pred$Resample == "Fold01",])` is 80 while `nrow(cars)` is 804

Comment: @missuse You are right, I indeed did not verify this for the reproducible example, but on my more complex one. In that case, I get the problem I mentioned in the previous comment. By applying your code to my 5-fold cv I obtain `nrow` equal to 80% of training data.

Comment: @missuse I edited the problem to make it more alike to my case and not it shows what I meant with 80% of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing CV in caret with folds created by `createFolds` function by default the train indexes are used. So when you did:

```
cv_folds <- createFolds(cars$Price, k = 5, list = TRUE)
```

you received train set folds

```
lengths(cv_folds)
#output
Fold1 Fold2 Fold3 Fold4 Fold5 
  161   160   161   160   162
```

each containing 20% of your data

then you specified these folds in trainControl:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", index = cv_folds, savePredictions = 'final')
```

from the help of `trainControl`:

> index - a list with elements for each resampling iteration. Each list
>   element is a vector of integers corresponding to the rows used for
>   training at that iteration.
>
> indexOut - a list (the same length as index) that dictates which data
>   are held-out for each resample (as integers). If NULL, then the unique
>   set of samples not contained in index is used.

So each time the model was built on 160 rows and validated on the rest. This is why

```
nrow(model$pred[model$pred$Resample == "Fold1",])
```

returns 643

What you should do is:

```
cv_folds <- createFolds(cars$Price, k = 5, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
```

now:

```
lengths(cv_folds)
#output
Fold1 Fold2 Fold3 Fold4 Fold5 
  644   643   642   644   643
```

and after training the model:

```
nrow(model$pred[model$pred$Resample == "Fold1",])
#output
160
```

Comment: BTW do you know why when I filter for "Fold05" I obtain indices that are in "Fold01" (generated by me)? What I mean is why there is some kind of an offset.

Comment: @abu, I either did not understand you or you are not correct. When I run: `lapply(unique(model$pred$Resample), function(x){
  sum(model$pred$rowIndex[model$pred$Resample == x] %in% model$pred$rowIndex[model$pred$Resample != x])
})` I get all 0, hence there is no overlap in the folds if you can post another question with an example of the issue I would be glad to attempt answer.

Comment: I think we did not understand each other. I have posted another question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458407/cross-validation-predictions-from-caret-in-assigned-to-different-folds). I would be grateful for some further help :)

Comment: @missuse that's great, just one question: aren't these predictions already given by the caret model object in $finalModel ?

Comment: @Agile Bean predictions are in `model$pred`. `$finalModel` contains the actual fitted model on all the train data using the best tuned parameters.

Comment: @missuse thank you. so just to clarify, your above calculations are identical with `model$pred` ?

Comment: @Agile Bean I am not sure what you mean, my above calculation is with `model$pred` where model is the object containing the output of the `train` function.

Comment: @missuse thanks for the clarification - i admit i confused it with another post i had read at the same time ;')