# Cross-validation predictions from caret in assigned to different folds

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I am wondering why predictions from 'Fold1' are actually predictions from the second fold in my predefined folds. I attach an example of what I mean.

```
# load the library
library(caret)
# load the cars dataset
data(cars)
# define folds
cv_folds <- createFolds(cars$Price, k = 5, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", index = cv_folds, savePredictions = 'final')
# fix the parameters of the algorithm
# train the model
model <- caret::train(Price~., data=cars, trControl=train_control, method="gbm", verbose = F)

model$pred$rowIndex[model$pred$Resample == 'Fold1'] %in% cv_folds[[2]]
```

Comment: Can you attach some output data? Maybe the averaged cross val scores is returned as the first index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resample data of `'Fold1'` are the records which are not in `cv_folds[[1]]`. These records are contained in `cv_folds` 2-5. This is correct as you are running a 5-fold cross-validation. Resample Fold 1 is tested against training the model on folds 2-5. Resample fold 2 is tested against training on folds 1, 3-5, and so on.

In summary: The predictions in `Fold1` are the test predictions from training a model on cv_folds 2-5.

**Edit: based on comment**

All the needed info is in the model$pred table. I added a bit of code for clarification:

```
model$pred %>% 
  select(rowIndex, pred, Resample) %>%
  rename(predection = pred, holdout = Resample) %>% 
  mutate(trained_on = case_when(holdout == "Fold1" ~ "Folds 2, 3, 4, 5",
                                holdout == "Fold2" ~ "Folds 1, 3, 4, 5", 
                                holdout == "Fold3" ~ "Folds 1, 2, 4, 5", 
                                holdout == "Fold4" ~ "Folds 1, 2, 3, 5", 
                                holdout == "Fold5" ~ "Folds 1, 2, 3, 4"))

  rowIndex predection holdout       trained_on
1      610   13922.60   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
2      623   38418.83   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
3      604   12383.55   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
4      607   15040.07   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
5       95   33549.40   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
6      624   40357.35   Fold2 Folds 1, 3, 4, 5
```

Basicly what you need for further stacking with the predictions are the `pred` and `rowIndex` columns from the model$pred table.

The rowIndex refers to the row from the original data. So rowIndex 610 refers to record 610 in the cars dataset. You can compare that the data in obs, which is the value of the Price column from the cars dataset.

Comment: What I am interested in is getting the predictions on the holdout folds for further stacking. So I would like to know predictions for fold 1 when the model is trained on folds 2-5. That is why i think that row indices from Resample data of `'Fold1'` should match those from `cv_folds[[1]]`. Is there some flaw in this logic?

Comment: @abu if you are interested in stacking mlr library has pretty good wrappers. Here is a [tutorial](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/files/571193/tutorial.pdf) - download link. On topic, `cv_folds[[1]]` has row indexes for all but the `Fold1 ` row indexes since `Fold1` is test and `cv_folds[[1]]` is train.

Comment: Of course, that is right. I should have seen it earlier! Thanks